# Starting multiple EC2 instances using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm getting the list of instances using the code below

```
    def list_instances_by_tag_value(self, tagkey, tagvalue):
    ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')
    response = ec2client.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'tag:'+tagkey,
                'Values': [tagvalue]
            }
        ]
    )
    instancelist = []
    for reservation in (response["Reservations"]):
        for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
            instancelist.append(instance["InstanceId"])
    return instancelist
```

Now the method `list_instances_by_tag_value` returns a `List`. Now I need to start the list of `EC2 instances`. So I'm doing something like below

```
def start_ec_instances(self, instanceids):
    response = ec2client.start_instances(InstanceIds=instanceids)
    return
```

where `instanceids` is the list returned from the first method. However `ec2client.start_instances` only accepts `String` and not a `List`.

I know I can convert the `list` to `String` and then parse it. I need to append (') in front of the instanceID and also append comma (,) between each instance ID.

question is, is there any easy easy way to do this rather than convert list to string and performing some `append` operation?

It needs to look something like `'i-XXXXXX', 'i-XXXXX', 'i-XXXXXXX'`

EDIT: When I pass the list to `start_instances` from the first method it says `Invalid type for parameter InstanceIds[0], value: ['i-ssss', 'i-YYYY', 'i-ZZZZ', 'i-KKKK'], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>`

Comment: From the error, it looks like you are passing a nested list. `[ [ inst1, inst2, ...]` ] instead of `[ inst1, inst2, ...]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are more likely calling it:

```
response = ec2client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[instanceids])
```

instead of:

```
response = ec2client.start_instances(InstanceIds=instanceids)
```

Answer (score 1):

`start_instances` [takes a list of strings](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html) in the `InstanceIds` field. Not sure where you are getting that it takes a comma separated string.

Comment: Because if I just pass the `list` from the first method to `start_instances` method it says `Invalid type for parameter InstanceIds[0], value: ['i-ssss', 'i-YYYY', 'i-ZZZZ', 'i-KKKK'], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>`

Comment: The documentation clearly says it takes a list. Maybe you are using a really old version of boto3? Try upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: I think I'm using the latest version `aws --version` shows `aws-cli/1.11.181 Python/3.6.3 Darwin/16.7.0 botocore/1.7.39` and `pip install boto3` also shows  `from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.8.0,>=1.7.0->boto3`

Comment: I see the issue now, you've got a bug in your code somewhere, although I don't see it in the code in your question. The error message `Invalid type for parameter InstanceIds[0], value: ['i-ssss', 'i-YYYY', 'i-ZZZZ', 'i-KKKK']` is telling you that the **first element** in the list is a list itself. see where it says `InstanceIds[0]`? You are nesting the lists somehow.

Comment: How did you figure it out from the error? I'm from `Java` world.

Comment: It said `InstanceIds[0]` has a value of list, when it expects a string. In other words the first element in the list is a list, not a string. The `[0]` in the error message was the key.